# Php shell script not working in windows

Tags: php

Following is my code

```
<?php  $output = shell_exec('ls -lart');   print $output;  ?>
```

Its working in linux system but its not work in windows system,

Comment: Linux and Windows are two different operating systems which understand different commands.

Answer (score 2):

[LS](http://francisconi.org/linux/comandos/ls) is a GNU/Linux utility. Try to use a windows equivalent like [dir](http://www.computerhope.com/dirhlp.htm). For example:

```
<?php  $output = shell_exec('DIR /S');   print $output;  ?>
```

Comment: No it's not. That's the answer.

Comment: @Sergiu Paraschiv It does not answer the question, the OP is asking why doesn't it works

Comment: Right, _Because _ "LS is a GNU/Linux utility.". He then also offers an alternative solution. This is the best answer there could be.

Comment: Well. The user didn't ask a question but let's solve the issue doing it more evident.